# Adding subview to UICollectionView using auto layout programmatically not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, autolayout, uisearchbar

I have a `UICollectionViewController` set up from a storyboard and it uses a flow layout. So far it is working fine i.e. its layout and cells are working as expected.

Now, I am trying to add a `UISearchBar` as a subview to the `UICollectionView`. This is how I am adding the search bar:

The flow layout's `sectionInset` is set to `UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0, 0, 0)` to make space for the search bar.

And added the following code in `viewDidLoad` :

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 44.0f)];
    // have also tried [[UISearchBar alloc] init] here.
[self.searchBar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

[self.collectionView addSubview:self.searchBar];

NSDictionary* viewDict = @{@"mySearchBar": self.searchBar};

NSArray* sHorizontal = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[mySearchBar]|"
                                                               options:0
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                 views:viewDict];


NSArray* sVertical = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[mySearchBar(==44)]"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:viewDict];

[self.collectionView addConstraints:sHorizontal];
[self.collectionView addConstraints:sVertical];
```

The constraints are very simple. Left, right and top edges of the `searchBar` are pinned to the left, right and top edges of the superview and its height is 44.

The problem is that the search bar is not visible when this code is run. I logged the frame values for the `searchBar` in `viewDidAppear` and found that its frame is set to (0, 0, 0, 44) i.e. the width is not getting resolved.

I also tried the visual format string `H:|[mySearchBar(>=768)]|` in which case the `searchBar` is visible and at its place but does not resize on orientation change i.e. remains 768 points wide in landscape too.

What am I doing wrong here? What should be done to get the desired layout constraints working?

I am trying this on an iPad simulator iOS 7.1.

I have also tried adding the search bar to the header view but it's behavior is different than what I require.

Comment: Why add the search bar programmatically if you have this in your `viewDidLoad`? It seems like it's independent of any other event.

Comment: This is the code I added to viewDidLoad to have a search bar. It was not there. The `searchBar` is a property I added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it!

I am still not sure why the previous approach was not working but I got the desired results like this:

```
NSDictionary* viewDict = @{@"mySearchBar": self.searchBar, @"myCollView": self.collectionView};

NSArray* sHorizontal = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[mySearchBar(==myCollView)]|"
                                                               options:0
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                 views:viewDict];


NSArray* sVertical = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[mySearchBar(==44)]"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:viewDict];

[self.collectionView addConstraints:sHorizontal];
[self.collectionView addConstraints:sVertical];
```

Notice the visual format string `H:|[mySearchBar(==myCollView)]|` that means the width of the search bar should be equal to the width of the collection view. The collection view is added to the `viewDict` dictionary as `myCollView`. This is working as expected and the search bar resizes on orientation changes.

A few points to note, earlier I also tried the same things using the `constraintWithItem:` method of the `NSLayoutConstraint` class. While the api is fairly easy to understand, it creates only one constraint. So we have to call it as many times as the number of constraints required, which can be tedious. Not only that, in my case, setting the 'equal width' constraint with this method was crashing and I could not figure out why.

On the other hand, `constraintsWithVisualFormat:` returns an array of all the constraints needed to satisfy the condition in the visual format string.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it's a search bar you want, you probably want it right above your collectionView. This is really easy in the storyboard: you just drag a search bar and search display controller right over your collection view. However, if you must do it programmatically, something like this should work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UISearchBar class]
            forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                   withReuseIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier"];

}

- (UIView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"reuseIdentifier";
    UISearchBar *searchBar = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                                                                withReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier
                                                                       forIndexPath:indexPath];
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    return searchBar;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I am aware of this. Please see the last line of the question. Its behavior does not match my requirement. Well, because if reloadData is called on the Collection view , the search bar gets cleared.